# Java Regex Alphanumeric match

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression in Java that will help me identify matches for alphanumerics with a specific format: 9 characters long with the first 5 for numbers `[0-9]`, the next three upper case characters `[A-Z]` and the last character being a number `[0-9]`. What I am trying now is the following:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{1,5}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{1}?$",
    Pattern.UNICODE_CASE).matcher(str.toString());

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Match found::" + m.group(0));
}
```

When I pass only the alphanumeric, e.g. `24135AB6`, the above code works and a match is found. However, if I pass a larger expression, e.g. `John goes 24135AB6 away back` or `24135AB6 24135AB6`, my code does not work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code would also work when passing only A234B, because `[0-9]{1,5}` means 1 to 5 occurences.

try using this regex:

```
^[0-9]{5}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]?$
```

Of course `24135AB6` will not work as input as you expect *three* alphabet characters, not just two.

Also, if you want to ignore any gibberish before the pattern, you need to remove the ^, if you want to ignore any stuff after the pattern, you need to remove the $ sign.

^ at the beginning means: My string must start exactly with what follows next

$ at the end means: My string must end with what i have defined here

Comment: Thank you .I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
The regex (?<=^|\\s) ensures that either start of the input or a white space before the sequence.
The regex (?<=^|\\s)[0-9]{1,5}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{1}\\b\\w* will find sequences that starts with a 5 numbers 3 Uppercase letters and 1 number followed by 0 or more words.


String input="24135ABE6 John goes 24135ABA6 away back 24135ABC6 24135ABD6A";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=^|\\s)[0-9]{1,5}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{1}\\b\\w*");

Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(input); 
while (matcher.find())
{
      System.out.println(matcher.group());
}

output:

24135ABE6
24135ABA6
24135ABC6
```